# Migrating Wicket 1.4.x to Wicket 7.9.x

Tags: wicket, migrating

I want to migrate Wicket from 1.4.9 to 7.9.0 but I haven't found any direct links. 
Can anyone provide me one?

Comment: You probably won't find a concrete guide from one specific version to the next. Instead iterate your way through the major releases since only those should introduce breaking changes and look at the [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+7.0] version first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no migration guide for direct upgrade from 1.4 to 7. You will have to do an incremental migration along the major release path:

1.4 -> 1.5 -> 6 -> 7

Each step can be found here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migrations

1.4 to 1.5: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5

1.5 to 6: 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+6.0

6 to 7:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+7.0

Comment: Thank you for that It is really helpfull